# ORDER BY versus DISTINCT in three-way LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sqlite

Consider the following tables.

```
CREATE TABLE asset (id INT PRIMARY KEY, ...other fields...);
CREATE TABLE property (id INT PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, value INT);
CREATE TABLE asset_property (asset_id INT, property_id INT);
```

I wish to select assets and order them on the basis of a property; however, I wish to include all assets in the list, not only those that have the property by which I am sorting.  For example, I might have

```
INSERT INTO asset VALUES (1, ...);
INSERT INTO property VALUES (1, 'x', 50);
INSERT INTO property VALUES (2, 'y', 60);
INSERT INTO asset_property VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO asset_property VALUES (1, 2);

INSERT INTO asset VALUES (2, ...);
INSERT INTO property VALUES (3, 'y', 70);
INSERT INTO asset_property VALUES (2, 3);

INSERT INTO asset VALUES (3, ...);
INSERT INTO property VALUES (4, 'x', 80);
INSERT INTO asset_property VALUES (3, 4);

INSERT INTO asset VALUES (4, ...);
```

I wish to select assets and order them by the "x" property.  This sounds like a LEFT JOIN to me.

```
SELECT asset.* FROM asset
LEFT JOIN asset_property ON asset.id = asset_property.asset_id
LEFT JOIN property ON asset_property.asset_id = property.id
                      AND property.name = 'x'
ORDER BY property.value;
```

However, the astute reader will notice that this will produce results such as this:

```
asset.id
1
3
1
2
4
```

There are two rows for asset 1 because there is one row due to the fact that asset 1 has a property named "x" and another row due to the fact that it has a property not named "x".

This is where my knowledge/understanding falls short.  To sidestep this problem, I attempted to use the DISTINCT keyword.

```
SELECT DISTINCT asset.* FROM asset
LEFT JOIN asset_property ON asset.id = asset_property.asset_id
LEFT JOIN property ON asset_property.asset_id = property.id
                      AND property.name = 'x'
ORDER BY property.value;
```

The trouble with this is that, at least under SQLite (3.12.1), the use of the DISTINCT keyword seems to override the ORDER BY clause: The rows are returned ordered by asset.id.

While I've little doubt that this database format will seem like the source of the problem rather than my lack of SQL wizardry, please save your energy rather than suggest that I change it; I know how to do that.  While the task at hand may not be *easy*, I'm hoping that it is *possible* and this format has other merits that make the contortions worth my while.  Thank you.

Comment: Something is wrong with your test data. PK violation for `property`, and did you really mean to insert only one row to `asset_property`?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Whoops!  Good catch.  I believe that I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making some assumptions about your test data, you should be able to avoid the need for `distinct`, using a little more SQL wizardry:

```
select a.id
from asset a
left join (
    select asset_id, value
    from asset_property ap 
    left join property p on p.id=ap.property_id 
    where p.name = 'x'
) xp on a.id=xp.asset_id
order by case when xp.value is null then 1 else 0 end, xp.value
```

The subquery contains only rows with `x` properties, then the main table is left-joined to that. This avoids multiple rows per `asset`, assuming that there can only be zero or one `x` property per asset.

Comment: Thank you!  Apparently I do not have enough reputation for my upvote to show even though this is my own question, but this does indeed do the trick.  I am most grateful, good sir.

Comment: Glad to hear it. You can still mark a (single) answer as "correct" by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the rows with property.name = 'x' you should use inner join ..

```
SELECT asset.* FROM asset
LEFT JOIN asset_property ON asset.id = asset_property.asset_id
INNER JOIN property ON asset_property.asset_id = property.id
                  AND property.name = 'x'
ORDER BY property.value;
```

Or with you last comment

```
SELECT asset.* FROM asset
LEFT JOIN asset_property ON asset.id = asset_property.asset_id
INNER JOIN property ON asset_property.property_id = property.id
                  AND property.name = 'x'
ORDER BY case property.value when is null the 1 else 0 end, property.value;
```

Comment: Thank you; however, I do _not_ only want rows with property.name = 'x'.  I want to sort by property.value when an asset has a property with name = 'x' but otherwise I wish to treat property.value as NULL and sort accordingly.

Comment: I don't understand .. please show a proper sample  of the  ordered result you need ..

Comment: Also, for the sake of anyone else playing around with it, in your answer, "asset_property.asset_id = property.id" should read "asset_property.property_id = property.id".

Comment: You can generate such a result yourself using the answer from @Blorgbeard, but with my sample data the desired result would be either 2,4,1,3 or 4,2,1,3 (no ordering applies between 2 and 4, which have no x property).

Comment: In the updated query, one needs `s/is null the/property.value is null then/`; however, this query returns the same results as the first—which is to be expected, because the only difference is that another ordering has been added; this does not change the set of results returned.  Assets without the 'x' property are still absent from the result set.  Is there something you find objectionable about @Blordbeard's answer?

Comment: if the query of Blordbeard's is correct for you and resolve your problem then mark the Blordbeard'  answer as accepted .. .. i don't undertsand because you are asking me ..

Answer (score 0):

What if you use a subselect: first select  distinct and then order?

```
Select * from (SELECT DISTINCT asset.*, property.value FROM asset LEFT JOIN asset_property ON asset.id = asset_property.asset_id LEFT JOIN property ON asset_property.asset_id = property.id AND property.name = 'x') ORDER BY property.value;
```

Check the syntax, it is only to try to explain the approach.

Comment: property.value is different for duplicated asset.id => distinct will not de-duplicate it